# Creating a numpy array from a .csv file but I can only get the 1st line in the array - what am I missing?

Tags: python, numpy

I have data in a file which looks like this

```
0.5,0,-21
0.5,0,-21
0.5,0,-19
0.5,0,-20
0.5,0,-20
1,0,-31
1,0,-28
1,0,-31
1,0,-28
1,0,-30
```

And I want to create a numpy array. I am doing the following to try copy it into an array:

```
with open ("bot1.csv") as fd:
    array = numpy.fromfile(fd, count=-1, dtype=float, sep=",")
```

But the resulting array is just:

```
array([  0.5,   0. , -21. ])
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use [numpy.loadtxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). It is faster than `genfromtxt()`—but less flexible, which should not matter in your case:

```
table = numpy.loadtxt('bot1.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Side note: it is best to not call you variable `array`, as this is also a name used by NumPy: this makes the code less convenient to paste after doing `from numpy import *` or `from pylab import *` (in a Python shell), because people can expect `array` to mean `numpy.array()`, and because the variable name shadows NumPy's `array()`.

Comment: .. not that `from numpy import *` is generally a good idea anyhow.  (Yes, I do it myself sometimes, when I'm lazy.)  In particular, the fact that after doing so `all(i > 10 for i in range(3))` gives `True` and not `False` is a major pitfall.  In any case, even without actual shadowing, the confusion itself is reason to avoid calling a specific array `array`.

Comment: @EOL When I use loadtxt I get the error could not convert string to float. I don't know why

Comment: @markmcmurray: Strange: I tried with Numpy 1.7 and a file with the data you give, and it works. Does your file contains other data? maybe are the newlines coded in a way that trips Numpy?

Comment: I found the problem, one of my samples (there are 1500) was missing a column so it was tripping numpy up - removed it and it works fine now.

Comment: Good! The more general `numpy.genfromtxt()` can handle missing values (`missing` argument).

Comment: @DSM: agreed, on `from numpy import *` having to be avoided if possible. That's why I only mentioned "in a Python shell" as a possible, reasonable use case.